# Calculating percentages for taxes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say that I have a tax of 17% over my services and I want to receive $20,000.00 regardless (after paying) the tax.

So I want something like: 
$$X - 17\% = \$20,000.00$$

Where $X$ is the final value that I need to charge to receive $\$20,000$.

How do I calculate this?

Comment: I think that you wrote this on wrong forum. Questions here should be on research level.

Comment: @Tomek: No, they are not. You are confusing this site with Mathoverflow. Questions of all levels are welcome here.

Comment: @Tomek: math.stackexchange.com is for math questions at *any* level.

Comment: Then sorry, I thought that it is research level forum just as TCS stackexchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28mathematics%29#Rule_of_Three) is your friend.

You want the 83% that is left to be $\$20,000$. If $X$ is 100% of what you need to charge, then you have:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
X &\longrightarrow &100\%\\\
20,000 &\longrightarrow&83\%
\end{array}$$
By the Rule of Three, to get the value of $X$ you multiply across the known diagonal and divide by the remaining quantity; so $X = \frac{(20,000)(100)}{83}\approx \$24,096.39$.

Answer (score 4):

Removing 17% leaves (100-17)%=83%, so you want 83%*x=20.000.  Divide both sides by 83% to get your answer.